# Qt windeployqt results in non-usable deployment

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, mingw32

I'm using `windeployqt` executable to do prepare my installation tree. The tool copies all required (and even some unnecessary) dlls into the designated folder, and does patching on Qt5Core.dll for hardcoded path variables. The following is how I execute the tool.

`C:\Qt\5.11.2\mingw53_32\bin>windeployqt.exe D:\Imaq
D:\Imaq\Imaq.exe 32 bit, debug executable
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicond.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets
Updating Qt5Cored.dll.
Updating Qt5Guid.dll.
Updating Qt5Networkd.dll.
Updating Qt5Svgd.dll.
Updating Qt5Widgetsd.dll.
Updating libGLESV2d.dll.
Updating libEGLd.dll.
Updating D3Dcompiler_47.dll.
Updating opengl32sw.dll.
Updating libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.
Updating libstdc++-6.dll.
Patching Qt5Cored.dll...
Creating directory D:/Imaq/bearer.
Updating qgenericbearerd.dll.
Creating directory D:/Imaq/iconengines.
Updating qsvgicond.dll.
Creating directory D:/Imaq/imageformats.
Updating qgifd.dll.
Updating qicnsd.dll.
Updating qicod.dll.
Updating qjpegd.dll.
Updating qsvgd.dll.
Updating qtgad.dll.
Updating qtiffd.dll.
Updating qwbmpd.dll.
Updating qwebpd.dll.
Creating directory D:/Imaq/platforms.
Updating qwindowsd.dll.
Creating directory D:/Imaq/styles.
Updating qwindowsvistastyled.dll.
Creating D:\Imaq\translations...
Creating qt_ar.qm...
Creating qt_bg.qm...
.
.`

From the above output, it looks like the tool is running without any errors. But after deployment, if I try to execute the binary, the following errors are shown.

[image]

From the error, it looks like wrong dlls are being copied. But, on my machine, I have only one compiler (mingw53_32) and there are no other possible versions of those dlls.

Note: I have installed Qt using the online installer, and I have only chose Qt creator, and Qt mingw from the list. Every other component listed in the installer was unchecked. I'm wondering if this issue is because of any missing components.

Also, I have tried switches like --debug, --compiler-runtime, although those switches doesn't seems to have anything to do with this problem. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am curious, why is it trying to use debug `dll`s (such as `Qt5Widgetsd.dll, Qt5Cored.dll`? Isn't it supposed to use release `dll`s? Did you build your app in Release mode?

Comment: You can deploy debug and release modes with `windeployqt` tool, depending on your needs.

Comment: `_ZdaPvj` is `operator delete[](void*, unsigned int)` - have you forgotten to implement it? This operator probably isn't provided by the runtime.

Comment: How do you find the mapping? And also, how do we know the implementation is not provided by the runtime?

Comment: To find the mapping, you need a demangler, there are online gcc demanglers available. The implementation may be provided by some runtime, but isn’t available at the time you run your executable. You can dump symbols from all the bundled libraries and you may notice that the symbol in question isn’t provided.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your `windeployqt` output, you are trying to deploy debug build of your application (as `windeployqt.exe` is copying `Qt5Cored.dll, Qt5Guid.dll, Qt5Networkd.dll', etc. libraries). You should try to deploy the release build of the app.

In Qt creator, you will find the option towards the left bottom, just above the run button. Build configurations for Debug and Release build can be accessed by clicking on "Projects" in the left toolbar while your project is open.

As specified in [Qt5.11.2 windeployqt is not creating finite dependent dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268285/qt5-11-2-windeployqt-is-not-creating-finite-dependent-dll)

Qt 5.11.2 is providing an option/flag along with windeployqt for creating dependencies associated with debug/release executable.

For creation of debug version dependent dlls:
**windeployqt executable --debug**

For creation of release version dependent dlls:
**windeployqt executable --release**

Comment: There is no difference in output when you try deploying release builds, except for the fact that the non-debug versions of DLLs will be copied. While it is not recommended to deploy debug builds, you are not forbidden from doing it. Either way, release deployment also has the same problem in my case.