# Qt5.11.2 windeployqt is not creating finite dependent dll

Tags: qt, mingw

When trying to run application with debug mode.. Error: "The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Core.dll was not found."

When trying to run application with release mode..

problem1: MinGW considering executable as debug executable and hence windeployqt is creating debug version dependent dll!

problem2: Getting same error as shown in above - "The code execution cannot proceed because Qt5Core.dll was not found.".

Can anyone provide solution for this? or request to guide for solving the problem.

Same problem was posted in-
[Qt windeployqt results in non-usable deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584794/qt-windeployqt-results-in-non-usable-deployment/53267689?noredirect=1#comment93420154_53267689)

Output of windeployqt

```
<executable path>windeployqt 
<executable name>.exe 
<executable name>.exe 32 bit, debug executable 
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicond.dll 
Skipping plugin qtvirtualkeyboardplugind.dll due to disabled dependencies (Qt5Qml Qt5Quick). 
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets 
All dependencies : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Widgets 
To be deployed : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Sql Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets 
Updating Qt5Cored.dll. 
Updating Qt5Guid.dll. 
Updating Qt5Networkd.dll.
Updating Qt5Sqld.dll. 
Updating Qt5Svgd.dll. 
Updating Qt5Widgetsd.dll. 
Updating libGLESV2d.dll. 
Updating libEGLd.dll. 
Updating D3Dcompiler_47.dll. 
Updating opengl32sw.dll. 
Updating libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll. 
Updating libstdc++-6.dll. 
Updating qsvgd.dll.
Updating qtgad.dll.
Updating qtiffd.dll.
Updating qwbmpd.dll.
Updating qwebpd.dll.
Creating directory <path of executable>/platforms. 
Updating qwindowsd.dll. 
Creating directory <path of executable>/sqldrivers. 
Updating qsqlited.dll. 
Updating qsqlmysqld.dll.
Updating qsqlodbcd.dll.
Updating qsqlpsqld.dll. 
Creating directory <path of executable>/styles.
Updating qwindowsvistastyled.dll. 
Creating <path of executable>\translations...
Creating qt_ar.qm... 
Creating qt_bg.qm...
Creating qt_ca.qm...
Creating qt_cs.qm...
Creating qt_da.qm...
Creating qt_de.qm...
Creating qt_en.qm...
Creating qt_es.qm...
Creating qt_fi.qm...
Creating qt_fr.qm...
Creating qt_gd.qm...
Creating qt_he.qm...
Creating qt_hu.qm...
Creating qt_it.qm...
Creating qt_ja.qm...
Creating qt_ko.qm...
Creating qt_lv.qm...
Creating qt_pl.qm...
Creating qt_ru.qm...
Creating qt_sk.qm...
Creating qt_uk.qm...
```

Comment: What is the output of `winqtdeploy`? And are you sure you are not mixing debug and release (for example an external loaded dll)?

Comment: How do you deployed the listed files eventually? Qt5Core.dll not found sonds like a path problem. Try to keep your exe in the same folder than your copy of Qt5Core.dll

Comment: @transistor Qt5Core.dll will generate as part of 'windeployqt <executable>' output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Qt 5.11.2 is providing an option/flag along with windeployqt for creating dependencies associated with debug/release executable.

For creation of debug version dependent dlls:

windeployqt executable **--debug**

For creation of release version dependent dlls:

windeployqt executable **--release**

This resolved my problem.